Representing $\Gamma(a-x)$ in terms of $\Gamma(kx)$ and $\Gamma(a)$ and elementary functions
I asked this question on MSE here.

I wonder if it is possible to represent $\Gamma(a-x)$ in terms of powers of $\Gamma(a)$, powers of $\Gamma(kx)$, and elementary functions. I am not looking for any other representation involving special functions like the beta function. Also, in the representation that I am seeking, the argument of the gamma function should only be $a$ or $kx$ (otherwise, the question is meaningless as $\Gamma(a-x)$ is already in closed form).
To be more precise, the representation that I am looking for is in the form of $f(x)\Gamma(a)^{m} \prod_{k=1}^N  \Gamma(kx)^{h(k)}$, where $h(k): \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $f(x)$ is an elementary function.
The representation is known when $a=1$, being the famous formula $\frac{\pi}{\Gamma(x)\sin(\pi x)}$ (and automatically, the representation exists for all integer $a$). The representation is also known when $a=\frac{1}{2}$, being $\frac{\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(x) 2^{2x-1} }{\sin\left(\pi x +\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\Gamma(2x)}$. (Also, the representation exists for all $n+ \frac{1}{2}$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$; in general, we need to find the representation for $a \in (0,1]$).
I don't think that this representation exists for all $a$, but it does exist for some values. Are there any other known representation forms for values other than $1$ and $\frac{1}{2}$? I couldn't find the representation for any other values.
I know this representation is not particularly useful, but it seems interesting.

Perhaps you should specify what "representation in terms of" exactly means: a rational function of $\Gamma(kx)$, $\Gamma(a)$ and elementary functions with rational coefficients? After all, $\Gamma(x-a)$ is itself a "representation in terms" of $\Gamma$ and $a$.

@AlexandreEremenko  finite combinations of elementary functions, powers of $\Gamma(a)$ and powers of $\Gamma(kx)$ with no other special functions or and the argument in the gamma function could only be $kx$ or $a$

I strongly suspect it exists only for half-integer $a$ and maybe this can be proved. Surely it can be proved for a large class of elementary functions by difference Galois theory.

@pie: what are "finite combinations"? Rational functions?

@AlexandreEremenko $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ where $f(x), g(x) $ is a combination of elementary functions and powers of $\Gamma(kx), \Gamma(a)$

@pie - I believe that they are asking you to pin down the ambiguity in the term "combination" (it's not a standard mathematical term). For example, you seem to not be allowing $g(x) = 1$ and $f(x) = \Gamma(x-a)$ even though it's not unreasonable to consider that $f(x)$ to be a "combination" of the functions $\Gamma(x)$ and $x-a$; it's the composition of those functions, after all.

It is highly unlikely that further useful identities of this form exist.  This can be seen by inspecting the poles and zeroes of the functions in the identities that do exist (noting from the Hadamard factorization theorem that such zeroes and poles determine meromorphic functions that are ratios of entire functions of finite order, up to elementary function factors):

$\Gamma(1-x)$ has simple poles at the natural numbers and no zeroes.  $\Gamma(x)$ has simple poles at the nonpositive integers and no zeroes.  $\sin(\pi x)$ has a simple zero at every integer and no poles.  The identity then reflects the fact that one can create the (indicator function of the) integers as a linear combination of the (indicator function of the) natural numbers and nonpositive integers.

$\Gamma(1/2-x)$ has simple poles at the positive half-integers and no zeroes.  $\Gamma(x)$ has  poles at the nonpositive integers and no zeroes.  $\Gamma(2x)$ has poles at the nonpositive integers and half-integers, and no zeroes.  $\sin(\pi x + \frac{x}{2})$ has zeroes at the half-integers, and no poles.  The identity then reflects the fact that one can create the (indicator function of the) half-integers as a linear combination of the (indicator function of the) positive half-integers, the nonpositive integers, and the nonpositive integers and half-integers.


More generally, if one had an identity of the form $\Gamma(a-x) = f(x) \Gamma(a)^m \prod_{k=1}^N \Gamma(kx)^{h(k)}$, then the (indicator function of the) zeroes and poles of $f$ would be some linear combination of the (indicator function of the) non-negative integers shifted by $a$, and the non-positive integers divided by $k$ for $k=1,\dots,N$.  One can convince oneself that outside of the examples already discussed (and small perturbations such as shifting $a$ by an integer), this is not going to generate periodic sets of zeroes or poles such as the integers or the half-integers, which could plausibly be related to trigonometric functions; instead, it will contain (indicators of) half-infinite arithmetic progressions, which strongly signal that such functions can't be expressed in any simpler form than a combination of Gamma functions.
See also this answer of mine to a previous MO question.
